# Programming with HLA

Tags: assembly, high-level, hla

I have been wanting to program with Assembly for a while now, and have finally found myself a good way to start getting involved with it.  I read a little bit on the "High Language Assembly" standard library, however, I have no idea how to start actually using it.  I also know that there are different kinds of Assembly (MASM, TASM, NASM) and I don't know which one I should use.  I used to use DOS-box for my low-level Assembly programming uses, although I'm not sure I can do the same thing for HLA.  If anyone can point me to a source that gets me started programming High Level Assembly, that would be fantabulous.  Or, if there's simply something I'm overlooking, please do tell.  Thank you!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Also, HLA is not as hot as it used to be. Nowadays C and C++ compilers regularly produce better code that macro assisted assembly. If you *really* want to get some advantage from assembly language you have to get down to the bare metal. And it's still hard to beat the compilers.

Comment: You should go to the official website (http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/HighLevelAsm/index.html), there is documentation as well as sample programs.

Comment: The only real way to beat an optimizing compiler in code generation is to build off of the compiler's output, tweaking it a bit, applying optimizations it missed. This means you have to (A) know C or C++, (B) know assembly language, and (C) have deep knowledge of the architecture you're targeting. Learning HLA is pretty pointless; it is a non-standard syntax that won't help you much in the real world. Just learn basic x86 assembly, which is super-useful even when you write in higher level languages, since it'll allow you to do address-level debugging. Any assembler is fine. They have...

Comment: minor syntactical differences, but that's something you get used to quick. When you're first learning, it might be most helpful to match your book to your assembler, so the syntax is the same, but after you know a little bit, you'll be able to handle the minor syntactical differences between assemblers without skipping a beat. MASM is a good choice if you're learning on Windows. NASM is a good choice for Linux/OS X, and will also work on Windows. Again, depends on what book you have, or what tutorial you're following.I can't personally recommend one, since I taught myself, but...

Comment: [this](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-X86-Assembly-Language-Programming/dp/1484200659/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1493374423&sr=1-1&keywords=x86-64+assembly) looks like a good one. There are lots of other great online resources linked in the [tag:x86] tag wiki here on Stack Overflow; definitely check those out. We don't otherwise do "recommendation"-style questions, because they're unmanageable and highly opinion-based. Anyway, you seemed earnest, so I thought I'd try and help you out anyway. Best of luck to you, and remember that *as you learn*, SO is a great resource for specific problems.